# [solved]Image appear every second page

Tags: graphics, xetex

I got code like given below. but `header-background.png` appear every second card. Not on all of them. Any ideas why? It is compiled by Xelatex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
         a4paper,
         total={55mm,90mm},
         left=0mm,
         top=0mm,
        }
% \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setstocksize{55mm}{90mm}
\setpagecc{55mm}{90mm}{*}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{[montserrat.bold.ttf]}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage{datatool}
% \usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\unitlength}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\unitlength}

\DTLloaddb{namelist}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{namelist}{%
    %% Map each column header in your .csv file to a command
    \Name=Name,
    \Club=Club%
}{
    \noindent
    \begin{figure}[!]
        \noindent
            \begin{picture}(90,15)
                \put(0,0){\includegraphics[height=15mm, width=90mm]{header-background.png}}
                \put(5, 7){\color{white}\Club}
            \end{picture}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{textblock}{60}(20,30)
        \textbf{\Name}
    \end{textblock}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using both geometry and memoirs own system. In the latter you're missing the all important `\checkandfixthelayout` without which the memoir interface does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Solution....

`papersize={55mm,90mm},` was misssing in definition of geometry